how to use different resolution than chart
I am trying to display a study on a different resolution than the chart shows.  I read the documentation but I think the resolution is hidden in some built in function that I cannot find.
In this case I am using the Pivot Point Supertrend study by LonesomeTheBlue.  It displays different trend lines depending on the chart time.  My goal is to display the indicator on the 4hr resolution even if my chart says 15min.
My issue is that I look at the code and I cannot find where it refers to any resolution so I am unsure where to edit it to make it display the supertrend for 4hr resolution only.
I pasted the code below, thanks!
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © LonesomeTheBlue

//@version=4
study("Pivot Point SuperTrend", overlay = true)
prd = input(defval = 2, title="Pivot Point Period", minval = 1, maxval = 50)
Factor=input(defval = 3, title = "ATR Factor", minval = 1, step = 0.1)
Pd=input(defval = 10, title = "ATR Period", minval=1)
showpivot = input(defval = false, title="Show Pivot Points")
showlabel = input(defval = true, title="Show Buy/Sell Labels")
showcl = input(defval = false, title="Show PP Center Line")
showsr = input(defval = false, title="Show Support/Resistance")

// get Pivot High/Low
float ph = pivothigh(prd, prd)
float pl = pivotlow(prd, prd)

// drawl Pivot Points if "showpivot" is enabled
plotshape(ph and showpivot, text="H",  style=shape.labeldown, color=na, textcolor=color.red, location=location.abovebar, transp=0, offset = -prd)
plotshape(pl and showpivot, text="L",  style=shape.labeldown, color=na, textcolor=color.lime, location=location.belowbar, transp=0, offset = -prd)

// calculate the Center line using pivot points
var float center = na
float lastpp = ph ? ph : pl ? pl : na
if lastpp
    if na(center)
        center := lastpp
    else
        //weighted calculation
        center := (center * 2 + lastpp) / 3

// upper/lower bands calculation
Up = center - (Factor * atr(Pd))
Dn = center + (Factor * atr(Pd))

// get the trend
float TUp = na
float TDown = na
Trend = 0
TUp := close[1] > TUp[1] ? max(Up, TUp[1]) : Up
TDown := close[1] < TDown[1] ? min(Dn, TDown[1]) : Dn
Trend := close > TDown[1] ? 1: close < TUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1], 1)
Trailingsl = Trend == 1 ? TUp : TDown

// plot the trend
linecolor = Trend == 1 and nz(Trend[1]) == 1 ? color.lime : Trend == -1 and nz(Trend[1]) == -1 ? color.red : na
plot(Trailingsl, color = linecolor ,  linewidth = 2, title = "PP SuperTrend")
 
plot(showcl ? center : na, color = showcl ? center < hl2 ? color.blue : color.red : na)

// check and plot the signals
bsignal = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1
ssignal = Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1
plotshape(bsignal and showlabel ? Trailingsl : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location = location.absolute, style = shape.labelup, size = size.tiny, color = color.lime, textcolor = color.black, transp = 0)
plotshape(ssignal and showlabel ? Trailingsl : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location = location.absolute, style = shape.labeldown, size = size.tiny, color = color.red, textcolor = color.white, transp = 0)

//get S/R levels using Pivot Points
float resistance = na
float support = na
support := pl ? pl : support[1]
resistance := ph ? ph : resistance[1]

// if enabled then show S/R levels
plot(showsr and support ? support : na, color = showsr and support ? color.lime : na, style = plot.style_circles, offset = -prd)
plot(showsr and resistance ? resistance : na, color = showsr and resistance ? color.red : na, style = plot.style_circles, offset = -prd)

// alerts
alertcondition(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1, title='Buy Signal', message='Buy Signal')
alertcondition(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1, title='Sell Signal', message='Sell Signal')
alertcondition(change(Trend), title='Trend Changed', message='Trend Changed')


I tried adding this line:
res = input(title="Use Different Timeframe? Uncheck Box Above", type=input.resolution, defval="W")
and it did add a dropdown menu to the settings to select a resolution but when I changed the chart resolution the plotted trend lines also changed each time.
